# php get value of document.getelementbyid

Tags: javascript, php

```
    <select style="width: 300px" id='Jproduk' name='selectJP' onchange="cekInput()">
        <option  value="" selected></option>
        <option  value="1">game</option>
        <option  value="2">itunes</option>
        <option  value="3">google</option>   </select>   
<script type="text/javascript">   
<?php $jprod= document.getElementById('Jproduk').value;?>   
</script>
```

How can I get the value of selected option and parsing it into `$jprod`?

Comment: `document.getElementById()` is not part of `php`. Is this inside a form?

Comment: That's wrong. 
`JS -> PHP = impossible (only if you send that info to PHP using POST or GET)  ,

PHP -> JS = possible   var text = <?php echo( $text ); ?> ;`

Comment: What is a purpose of fetching the same form value in the same page?

Comment: You are mixing PHP and javascript. In javascript you could do `var jvalue = document.getElementById('Jproduk').value;;`

Comment: this part of code is from my codeigniter view, i want to parse the document.getelement value to my controller function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is absurd.

Comment: also see https://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/ClientSide01CD/page_18.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not assign javascript variable value directly to PHP variable like this, if you want to do so; you can get pass value of javascript variable to PHP code by using AJAX call.

Try following code snippet

```
<select style="width: 300px" id='Jproduk' name='selectJP' onchange="cekInput()">
    <option  value="" selected></option>
    <option  value="1">game</option>
    <option  value="2">itunes</option>
    <option  value="3">google</option>   
</select>   

<script type="text/javascript">
function cekInput() {
    var selectJP = document. getElementById('Jproduk').value;
    // value of selected option
    alert(selectJP);

    // To pass this value in php you can do AJAX stuff here    
}
</script>
```

Comment: but im really dummy at using ajax stuff, could it be like this? `<?php $selectJP = selectJP; ?>`

Comment: No, you can't do `<?php $selectJP = selectJP; ?>` like this.

Comment: what should i do then? i dont get it, im stuck on it

Comment: Please explain more in detail; so we can instruct you accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.
This is correct solution.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select style="width: 300px" id='Jproduk' name='selectJP' onchange="cekInput()">
        <option  value="" selected></option>
        <option  value="1">game</option>
        <option  value="2">itunes</option>
        <option  value="3">google</option>   </select>   

<script>

function cekInput(){
     $jprod= document.getElementById('Jproduk').value;
     alert($jprod);
}
</script>
```

Comment: but why i cant directly use $jprod in my php code? thank you in advance

Comment: $jprod= document.getElementById('Jproduk').value; this code not working

Answer (score -1):

In case `$jprod = document.getElementById('Jproduk').value;` not getting any  element then `document` does not have this `id="Jproduk"`.

Check for any typo.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, you are mixing PHP with js.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).